# Connected Sum: Actual Example

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Suppose I have two tori as in the image:[image: Two tori]

I have parameterizations of each torus and I want to form a nice $C^\infty$ connected sum.
How do I do this?

I know the theory, but not the practice. How do I find a suitable patch to cover the connecting throat between the two tori? I assume that you define a curve in each torus to represent the boundary and then some how smoothly extend the remaining surfaces toward each other. Does anyone know how this is actually done? At the end of the day I'd like a set of charts that cover the whole 2-torus in a smooth manner.

Comment: Your picture suggests to me that you are interested in having the connected sum be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's right.